# Why EditText is not updating after changing language in settings?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm creating an app where I need to quickly test some different languages. I've got 3 string resource files, values/strings.xml, values-es/strings.xml, and values-fr/strings.xml. Each of the files have their respective translated strings.

When I launch the app, I'm preloading some text into a TextView (Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage) and text that I pull in from an array in the xml file and assign one string to an EditText:

```
<string-array name="some_text">
    <item>Overall, how severe were your flu symptoms today?  Please select one response only.</item>
    <item>No flu symptoms today</item>
    <item>Mild</item>
    <item>Moderate</item>
    <item>Severe</item>
    <item>Very Severe</item>
</string-array>
```

I set the text of the language label like this:

```
 languageTxt = findViewById(R.id .language_text)
 languageTxt.text = Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage
```

Then load the strings in the array and set one of them to the EditText like this:

```
textList = resources.getStringArray(R.array.some_text)
editTxt = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)
if(textList.isNotEmpty()) {
    val txt = textList[currentIndex] //currentIndex = 0
    editTxt.setText(txt)
}
```

textList, languageTxt, and editTxt are declared private like:

```
private lateinit var textList: Array<String>
private lateinit var languageTxt: TextView
private lateinit var editTxt: EditText
```

The first run through onCreate, everything works fine. If the language is set to Spanish, both languageTxt and editTxt are in Spanish as expected. Then if I go to settings and change the language to French, when I bring my app back to the foreground, the languageTxt says French (well spelled in French). Then I watch in the debugger, the textList loading the text, and it's all the French strings like I expected. The problem I'm seeing is when I set editText, the control isn't updating to display the French string. It's still in Spanish. I can clearly see that the text is in French, but calling setText() doesn't seem to be working. I've tried clearing the exitTxt first, setting it to null, empty, etc, nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what's going on here? I've been scratching my head for a couple hours. Ugh

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Giddy Naya's answer for giving me a hint on what is going on. Android saves the state of the app when it goes in the background so that it's the same when it comes back to the foreground. It's so strange, because even a editTxt.setText() doesn't work and gets overridden by Android. So what I had to do is set the new state of app (i.e. update the text) in the onResume function:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if(textList.isNotEmpty()) {
       val txt = textList[currentIndex]
       editTxt.setText(txt)
    }
}
```

If you're new to Android, this feature can make debugging quite a pain, since you're trying to set a new state in onCreate and it doesn't change.

I'm still not sure why setting a TextView works in onCreate() but setting an EditText does not.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in foreground during language changes your UI may need reloading onResume so expected resources can be loaded. 
You can save the default language in preference and check for value changes onActivityResume and if true then reload UI.

Something like

```
override fun onResume() { 
    super.onResume()
    ...
    if (localeHasChanged)
      setContentView(R.layout.xxx) //force UI reload
    ...
}
```

Comment: setContentView is being called because the app detects that there was a config change (i.e. the language) when it comes back into the foreground. The issue is that EditText isn't getting updated even when calling editTxt.setText()

Comment: Can you confirm that your code is entering the block where you call **.setText()**? i.e using a Toast

Comment: Yes, it's entering. But I think I've figured it out. Your override example led me to the answer. The issue is based on the bundle being saved. I think Android is caching the state of the app so that it's in the same state when it comes out of the background. What I had to do is set the text again in onResume and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I had the same behaviour and I was struggling for hours.